# Ansible only outputs all information on failure when bin_ansible_callbacks set to True

Tags: ansible

Running adhoc commands in ansible with the configuration variable `bin_ansible_callbacks = False`, on both a success and failure ansible outputs `ansible_facts`,`changed`,`rc`,`stderr`,`stderr_lines`,`stdout`, and `stdout_lines`.

```
hostname.example.com | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "Info: Using environment 'development'\nInfo: Retrieving pluginfacts\nInfo: Retrieving plugin\nInfo: Retrieving locales\nInfo: Lodaing facts\nInfo: Caching catalog for hostname.example.com\nInfo: Applying configuration version '1660221776'\nNotice: Applied catalog in 12.29 seconds\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Info: Using environment 'development'",
        "Info: Retrieving pluginfacts",
        "Info: Retrieving plugin",
        "Info: Retrieving locales",
        "Info: Loading facts",
        "Info: Caching catalog for hostname.example.com",
        "Info: Applying configuration version '1660221776'",
        "Notice: Applied catalog in 12.29 seconds"
    ]
}
```

When the configuration variable `bin_ansible_callbacks = True`, on a failure ansible has similar output, in the format specified by `stdout_callback`, but `stderr_lines` and `stdout_lines` are omitted.

```
PLAY [Ansible Ad-Hoc]

TASK [puppet]
fatal: [hostname.example.com]: FAILED! => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python
  disabled: false
  error: true
  msg: puppet did not run
  rc: 1
  stderr: |-
      Error: Connection to https://puppet:8140/puppet-ca/v1 failed, trying next route: Request to https://puppet:8140/puppet-ca/v1 timed out connect operation after 120.001 seconds
      Wrapped exception:
      Error: No more routes to ca
      Error: Could not run: No more routes to ca
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

PLAY RECAP
hostname.example.com    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

However, when the configuration variable `bin_ansible_callbacks = True`, on a success, ansible only outputs `ok: [hostname]` (with `stdout_callback = yaml` in this case).

```
PLAY [Ansible Ad-Hoc]

TASK [puppet]
ok: [hostname.example.com]

PLAY RECAP
hostname.example.com    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Is it possible to have an ad-hoc command output all of those fields on a success with `bin_ansible_callbacks = True`? Is it possible to have `stdout_lines` and `stderr_lines` not be omitted on a failure?

I would like the same information with that I get with `bin_ansible_callbacks = False`, but with the formatting that `bin_ansible_callbacks = True` provides (specifically with `stdout_callback = yaml` set).